# Is an encrypted .dmg file decrypted on the dropbox server?

Tags: encryption, web-application, server

I'd like to use built in tools to create an encrypted drive in OS X that I can sync with Dropbox.  To this end, I've created a 'sparse bundle' encrypted volume (.dmg) that remains in ~/Dropbox.

My understanding is that when I open (decrypt) this volume, it mounts at /Volumes and the decrypted information is never visible to the Dropbox server.  Is this true?

Comment: Eventually, you want to use truecrypt containers, dropbox will sync them incrementally. you can auto-mount tcrypt containers by running: cryptsetup --type tcrypt open (ubuntu)

Comment: @hub huh?  truecrypt went defunct some time back... what advantage would that offer anyway?

Comment: seemingly, dmg files are synced incremental too (dropbox does bindiffs). i didnt know about that, please ignore my last comment.

Comment: A dmg (disk image) is a plain file, while a sparsebundle is a directory with files (bands) of fixed size. TrueCrypt and sparseimages use files, too, so sparsebundles have the best chances of being synchronized incrementally, though Dropbox might be smart enough to detect blocks of changes within files to sync (on the server, it does detect them to deduplicate them along with data of all users).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as long as you are **mounting** using `diskutil` and not decrypting to the current working directory.

This is because the decryption is happening on the fly based on the data in the image when a encrypted image is mounted.

Please note that modifying any data in the mounted, encrypted dmg will re-encrypt the dmg to contain the changes such that Dropbox will think it has changed. This might lead to a lot of re-uploading, since ~/Dropbox is usually watched for changes and any changes instantly uploaded by the Dropbox app.

Please also note that for Dropbox, this is just a big ball of data that changes - as the dmg is chunked into 8 MiBiBytes chunks, a small change thus may lead to 8 MiBiBytes reuploading. Which is basically a good thing, security-wise, but might be unexpected and/or undesired in terms of bandwidth use.

I am unsure as to how Dropbox identifies what has to be uploaded with dmg files. Using `diff` may work but seems unlikely as there would have to be a shadow copy of every file for `diff`ing - and dmgs might get big :)

Comment: It mounts to /Volumes/my_encrypted_volume.  Is mount point where it is decrypted?  I didn't realize changes would result in re-encryption of the whole volume, but I suppose this is a security feature.  Is this affected by the disk util options when creating the volume: sparse bundle image, sparse disk image, read/write disk image?

Comment: It does not reencrypt everything, probably. But Dropbox will not be able to tell changes, so the whole will will be considered overwritten. The mount point is where the decrypted files are accessible - the actual decryption happens in-memory, afaik.

Comment: "*changes will (re)upload all of that*"; "*Dropbox will not be able to tell changes*" - that's not true. See [Does Dropbox always upload/download the entire file any time a change is made?](https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/8)

Comment: @techraf with AES-CBC? I'm quite interested in how not every full chunk of a dmg must be uploaded when something changes.

Comment: How do you define "every full chunk of a dmg"?

Comment: @techraf if OP uses a bundle image rather than a disk image, they are split in to chunks (of 8 MiBiBytes) internally, those must be completely re-uploaded at the very least. If not, one change can yield up to everything to change.

Comment: So what's your conclusion? Dropbox uploads changed chunks or "one big ball of data treated as single file"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37387/discussion-between-smokedispenser-and-techraf).