# when/how does an encrypted volume .dmg change to reflect the file system it stores

Tags: encryption, aes, file-encryption, macos

I'm trying to verify that storing a `.dmg` file stays encrypted while only the mounted file system is unencrypted (see [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/118262/is-an-encrypted-dmg-file-decrypted-on-the-dropbox-server/118270?noredirect=1#comment214235_118270)).  My thought was to create a `.dmg` containing a text file, make a copy of the `.dmg`, then track file changes with `cmp -b myvol.dmg myvol2.dmg | less - N` after various actions; my hope was that the `.dmg` wouldn't change until I unmounted the volume, at which point it would be updated and re-encrypt the file.  It looks like I was wrong, though.

Both .dmg files remain identical after mounting and opening the (identical) text files, but can be seen to differ by at least several thousand bytes after a single character change.  Apparently the .dmg is diffusely (good!) updating to reflect changes in the file system, but unfortunately is a bit of a null result in my experiment.

**My Question: How can I verify that unencrypted information isn't stored in the .dmg file?**  Is it simply enough to say that a .dmg is not directly readable, and can't be mounted without the password?  I'm an encryption novice who wants to verify things directly.

Thanks!